# Get common list elements between list and a nested list in python

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, list-comprehension

I want to extract the list element from listB if listB[0] is present in ListA

```
listA = ["A", "B"]
listB = [("F",4),("A",7),("C",5)]
```

expected list: `[("A",7)]`

---

I tried:

```
[[i for i in listB if x == i[0]] for x in listA]
```

But im getting this result : `[[('A', 7)], []]`

i tried to do it with MAP and lamda too but im getting an error.
can someone tell me where the error is exactly

`list(map(lambda x: i for i in listB if x == i[0], listA))`

Comment: That map() example is a syntax error. Python can't parse it, and I can't either. There are multiple problems with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to make one loop. The `in` operator will do the other one.

```
>>> listA = ["A", "B"]
>>> listB = [("F",4),("A",7),("C",5)]
>>> [pair for pair in listB if pair[0] in listA]
[('A', 7)]
```

There is an equivalence between comprehensions and the map and filter functions. But the equivalent map-and-filter for this one doesn't need the `map()`:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda pair: pair[0] in listA, listB))
[('A', 7)]
```

The idiomatic Python style is to prefer the comprehension version if you would have to make a lambda.